# Handling B64 encoded data in Python

Tags: python

In my Google App Engine based app, I am fetching data from a SOAP webservice.
The problem is that one of the tag contains binary 64 encoded data. I decode it using

```
decodedStr = base64.b64decode(str(content))
```

It seems that the decoding is not done correctly a I get garbage data in decodeStr. I think the problem is that the content string is falsely parsed as a unicode string instead of simple byte string

Can any Python guru tell me how to handle b64 encoded data in Python?

For now I am using this workaround

```
fileContent = str(fileContent)
fileContent = fileContent[3:-3]
self.response.out.write(base64.b64decode(fileContent))
```

Comment: Wait...this is really confusing.  Manually excluding content is resulting in valid b64 decoded data?  Does 'content' include extraneous (non b64 encoded). Data?

Comment: The value sent by webservice does not contain any non encoded data. but when I convert it to str, the value is encapsulated by these characters  u'( . So Just to remove these characters I trim 3 characters. After that the b64decode function converts the data correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you have an answer to your question -- but I thought it might help to point out that if the string actually includes prefixed such as you quoted, then it is not a clean b64 stream. It sounds like the webservice is sending you a python-formatted unicode string, and your app is swallowing it with the unicode prefix. Actually, if the variable name 'fileContent' is an indication it came from a file, it sounds like someone streamed a unicode string to a file, and your app swallowed it whole from there (with the prefix)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using base64.decodestring or if you were passed an url base64.urlsafe_b64decode.
Make sure that the data is not in base16 or base32.

Answer (score 0):

Strange.  If the content were not b64 encoded, the call to decode should raise a TypeError exception. I assume that's not happening?

Which would lead me to wonder how you know the resulting decodedStr is not what your after?